# Caliburn.Micro attach event handler on event of Behavior

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml, caliburn.micro, behavior

I wrote my own Behavior to handle a swipe gesture and put it to the ItemTemplate of a ListView. If a swipe is completed, I raise an event for LeftSwipe or RightSwipe. This event should be handled by my ViewModel.

I use the syntax of Caliburn.Micro to attach handler to an event: `cm:Message.Attach="[Event LeftSwipe] = [LeftSwipe($source, $eventArgs)"`.

This is my Behavior:

```
public class SwipeInteractionBehavior : DependencyObject, IBehavior
{
    public DependencyObject AssociatedObject { get; private set; }

    public void Attach(DependencyObject associatedObject)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public void Detach()
    {
        // ...
    }

    public event EventHandler LeftSwipe;

    public event EventHandler RightSwipe;

    // ...
    // ...

    private void OnLeftSwipe(FrameworkElement element)
    {
        // ...

        if (LeftSwipe != null)
        {
            LeftSwipe(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    private void OnRightSwipe(FrameworkElement element)
    {
        // ...
        if (RightSwipe != null)
        {
            RightSwipe(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }

    }
}
```

This is how I use this Behavior inside of ListViews ItemTemplate:

```
        <ListView x:Name="Links" IsItemClickEnabled="True" SelectionMode="None" cm:Message.Attach="[Event ItemClick] = [Click($source, $eventArgs)]">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid>
                            <Border x:Name="todoItem" Loaded="Border_Loaded" Background="White">
                                <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                    <local:SwipeInteractionBehavior cm:Message.Attach="[Event LeftSwipe] = [LeftSwipe($source, $eventArgs)]" />
                                </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

                                <Grid>
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Style="{ThemeResource ListViewItemContentTextBlockStyle}" />
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Url}" Style="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSubheaderTextBlockStyle}" />
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Tags, Converter={StaticResource ListToString}}" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

I ran in an exception if I raise the LeftSwipe event, this is my StackTrace:

```
System.Exception was not handled.
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=No target found for method LeftSwipe.
  Source=Caliburn.Micro.Platform
  StackTrace:
       at Caliburn.Micro.ActionMessage.Invoke(Object eventArgs)
       at Caliburn.Micro.TriggerAction`1.Execute(Object sender, Object parameter)
       at Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity.Interaction.ExecuteActions(Object sender, ActionCollection actions, Object parameter)
       at Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core.EventTriggerBehavior.OnEvent(Object sender, Object eventArgs)
       at ReaderApp.SwipeInteractionBehavior.<>c__DisplayClass5.<OnLeftSwipe>b__4()
       at ReaderApp.Extensions.FrameworkElementExtension.<>c__DisplayClass2.<Animate>b__0(Object s, Object e)
  InnerException:
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly IEventAggregator eventAggregator;
    private readonly Database database;

    public BindableCollection<Link> Links
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public MainViewModel(INavigationService navigationService, IEventAggregator eventAggregator, Database database)
        : base(navigationService)
    {
        this.eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
        this.database = database;

        Links = new BindableCollection<Link>();
    }

    public async void LeftSwipe(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public void RightSwipe(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like it can't find the LeftSwipe method, can you share the view model code for LinkViewModel (or whatever is bound to the ListView)

Comment: I added the ViewModel code. If I implement the SwipeInteraction as ContentControl, it works without any problem. It seems to be not possbile to use attached properties on Behaviors.

Comment: I'll need to look into it, another possible approach is to implement the SwipeInteraction as a trigger which uses ActionMessage as an action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem is that `ActionMessage` inherits `TriggerAction<FrameworkElement>` which means it can't attach correctly to `SwipeInteractionBehavior`.

It's also complicated by the fact there's some major API differences between the WPF / Silverlight / Windows Phone 8 Interactivity SDK and the WinRT Interactivity SDK. You can see a bit of what I mean in the [Parser](https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/blob/master/src/Caliburn.Micro.Platform/Parser.cs#L88) comments.

What I'd recommend is implementing `SwipeInteractionBehavior` as a *Trigger Behaviour* much like `EventTriggerBehavior`, this used to be a separate base class but with WinRT it's still `IBehavior`, the difference is that it has a property called Actions of type `ActionCollection`. Stupidly there is no interface is base class enforcing this so Caliburn.Micro is stuck making some assumptions.

You'd then use `Interaction.ExecuteActions` to trigger those actions, in the end your xaml should look something like.

```
<Border x:Name="SwipeTarget">
  <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <local:SwipeEventBehavior Direction="Left">
      <cm:ActionMessage AssociatedObject="{Binding ElementName=SwipeTarget" Method="LeftSwipe" />
    </local:SwipeEventBehavior>
  </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Border>
```

It's a bit more long winded, but we need to work around the limitations imposed by the changes in the SDK.